# Teamcity Build - Issue with Entityframework (.NET)

Tags: .net, teamcity, msbuild-4.0

I am trying to configure a build or my ASP.NET MVC3 project. The build fails at my domain project. It fails to find classes for System.Data.Entity.dll, though I have copied them locally and also installed at my build server.

My other projects (without using entityframework) are building fine.

Here is my output from teamserver build.

http://pastebin.com/hY5mjrYW

Thanks,
Naveen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, got it. I need to copy the missing file "C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" from my dev machine to my build server.

This means I do not need to install VS 2010 SP1 and this automatically resolves my nuget dependecies :)

More from the following link

http://handcraftsman.wordpress.com/2010/07/20/resolving-error-msb4019-microsoft-webapplication-targets-was-not-found/